# Set/Query columns form secondary compound key with CQL3

Tags: cassandra, cql3

Say I have the following CF with compound Primary Key

```
CREATE TABLE dpt (
     empID int,
     deptID int,
     PRIMARY KEY (deptID, empID));
```

Because of the compound PK, cassandra will create one row for each dept, and the employee IDs that are members of the department will be stored as columns on that row with the :empID as the column name.

Quesiton #1: can I set a value to that column (e.g the employ name) with `CQL3`? if so, how?

Question #2: can I see the value of `<individual_employ_ID>:empID` column - if exists - with `CQL3`?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Question #1:
CREATE TABLE dpt (
     empID int,
     deptID int,
     empName text,
     PRIMARY KEY (deptID, empID));

Question #2:
Please take a look at the examples: 
http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/INSERT
http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/UPDATE

Comment: #1: empName then becomes a new column. I was wondering if I can do something like INSERT INTO dpr (<individual_employ_ID>:empID) VALUES ('employname'); but that's mostly a theoritical question. I just want to know if that's possible and not really having a use case